# python dictionary assigning wrong keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, docx

Iam extracting test from word document tables using python docx, I am looping through multiple docx files. The data comes in a form of a list of dictionaries. The issue I am having is that the list of dictionaries has assigned some of the keys as values and some of the values as keys. I am trying to find a way to reassign so of the keys and values

here is a sample of the current dictionary:

```
[
  {'Title': 'Purpose', 'Analysis of Data ':'To analyze data'},
  {'Title': 'test data', 'Analysis of Data ':'To analyze data'}
]
```

The two string before the comma are supposed to be the keys and the two strings after the commas are supposed to be the values

so what can I rearrange these list of dictionaries so that they can look like the image below?

```
[
  {'Title': 'Analysis of Data ', 'Purpose': 'To analyze data'},
  {'Title': 'test data', 'Purpose': 'To analyze data'}
]
```

The code (adjusted from the comment):

```
data_t = []
def getTable(filename): 
    document = Document(filename)
    table = document.tables[0]
    keys = None
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows): 
        text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells) 
        if i == 0: 
            keys = tuple(text) 
            continue 
        row_data = dict(zip(keys, text)) 
        data_t.append(row_data) 

path = (r'C:\Users\OyooP\Desktop\auto1*.docx')
files=glob.glob(path) 
table_list = [] 
for f in files: 
    tbl_corpus = getTable(f) 
    table_list.append(tbl_corpus) 

corpus_list[0] 
data_t
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the source data? How did you try to extract? We need more information about what you tried to do exactly.

Comment: Umm, some of the desired text is not in your original dict

Comment: You should instead fix the original code for the extraction and run it again.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the extract was 2 part the  header of the document and the text from a table.. The header of the document works just fine and the dictionary is normal. This second section is the extraction from the table, and this is how it appears. The same code, only difference is  this extracts from a table as opposed to the header of the word document

Comment: @dpwrussell was just giving an example the main take away is is there a way to reassign the section  in the dictionary before the comma to be the keys and the section after the comma to be values

Comment: @tmrlvi the source data is a word document with a header a table with data in it and a paragraph, below thw table

Comment: @tmrlvi   data_t = []
def getTable(filename):
    document = Document(filename)    
    table = document.tables[0]
        keys = None
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)        
        if i == 0:
            keys = tuple(text)
            continue
        row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
        data_t.append(row_data)    
path = (r'C:\Users\OyooP\Desktop\auto1\*.docx')
files=glob.glob(path)
table_list = []
for f in files:    
    tbl_corpus = getTable(f)
    table_list.append(tbl_corpus)
    corpus_list[0]      
data_t

Comment: What is the class `Document`? What package do you use?

Comment: @tmrlvi i use  python-docx  " from docx import Document"

Answer (score 0):

As commented, It *is* better to fix this problem from the source.

But anyways, this could help with the "rearrangement":

Basically we have: `input = {'A': 'B', 'C':'D'}`

And we want: `output = {'A':'C', 'B':'D'}`

There's an attribute in dicts `.items()` which:

> returns a list of key-value pairs in a dictionary.

So we could do something like:

```
    Given: 
    d = {'A': 'B', 'C':'D'}

    >> list(d.items())
    >> [('A', 'B'), ('C','D')]

    So we could do something like:

    >> list(d.items())[0][1]
    >> 'C'
```

With this we can retrieve any key or value, so now we can try to rearrange it.

So I generalized the .items() part and rearranged it with this method:

```
def arrange_dict(input):
    for i in range(len(input)):
        for j in range(len(input)):
            if j == len(input):
                break
            value = list(input.items())[i][j]
            if i != j:
                if i < j:
                    new_key = value
                    next_val = list(input.items())[i+1][j]
                    input.update({new_key:next_val})
                else:
                    input.pop(value)
                    new_val = value
                    prev_key = list(input.items())[i-1][j]
                    input.update({prev_key:new_val})
```

And now you can arrange every dict inside the list like this:

```
    for dict in list:
        arrange_dict(dict)
```

Hope it helps, and if anyone gets to refactor this, please, feel free to post it ;)

Comment: Hi Airle thanks for your response. I tried  your example and i am receiving this error-             
            -----------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-bfe18a2a80d6> in <module>
      5         if j == len(input):
      6             break
----> 7         value = list(input.items())[i][j]
      8 
      9         if i != j:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: That's because the `input` has to be a dict, not the whole list, you have to pass every dict trough a for loop for example as shown above.